# Access specifics of ValueError in pandas.read_excel() converters

Tags: python, pandas, traceback, valueerror, converters

I'm using the following to ensure a dataframe column has the correct data type before I proceed with operations:

```
>>> cfun = lambda x: float(x)
>>> df = pd.read_excel(xl, converters={'column1': cfun})
```

Using converters instead of dtype so that the traceback will tell me explicitly what value caused the issue:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '100%'
```

What I would like to do is take that information (that the string "100%" was the problem) and tell the user where it occurred in the dataframe/file. How can I get that information from the exception in order to get a row index and, say, print the entire row?

*Note: Adding the percent sign isn't the only mistake my users make, otherwise I'd just replace any '%' with ''.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can check by first reading in the csv, and then checking which rows wouldn't convert. This finds them all at once, instead of one by one with the `ValueError`.

Just remember, python begins numbering at 0 and wont include the header so the row indices of the `df` will be off from those in the csv (by 1 or 2).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(xl)

# Example df
   column1 column2
0      100       A
1     100%       B
2  112,312       C
3      171       D
4  123.123       E
5      NaN       F

df['column1_num'] = pd.to_numeric(df.column1, errors='coerce')
bad_mask = (df.column1_num.isnull()) & ~(df.column1.astype('str').str.lower().isin(['nan']))

bad_rows = df[bad_mask].index.values
#array([1, 2], dtype=int64)

df[bad_mask]
#   column1 column2  column1_num
#1     100%       B          NaN
#2  112,312       C          NaN
```

I updated the mask because `float` is able to handle the `'NaN'` string, so it wont actually show up as an issue in your read, though `pd.to_numeric` still coerces it to `NaN`.

```
float('NaN')
#nan
pd.to_numeric('NaN')
#ValueError: Unable to parse string "NaN" at position 0
```

Comment: Do you know why I'd be getting an AttributeError on the bad_mask line? "Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: @ExcelHelp Yeah, sorry it should have been a string first, I updated it.