# How to read the data with special characters in xlsx file using pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlsx

I want to read the xlsx file in the pandas data frame and perform some operations on the data. I am able to read the file with the command:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
```

but when I am trying to perform some operation on the data, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:''disc abc r14jt mt cxp902 5 r2eu fail''
```

How I can resolve this problem. I already tried encoding='utf-8' but then also I am getting the error.

Actually I have one xlsx file 'original.xlsx', I am filtering some data from that file and saving that data as 'file.xlsx' with below command:

```
original.to_excel("file.xlsx",index=False,header=['a','b','c'],engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Now when I am trying to read the 'file.xlsx' file and perform some operation on it, I am getting that error. Is there any issue in the way I am saving the file or while reading it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access specifics of ValueError in pandas.read\_excel() converters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49902930/access-specifics-of-valueerror-in-pandas-read-excel-converters)

Comment: Perform that operation only on suitable data.

Answer (score 1):

```
xl_file = pd.ExcelFile(file_name)

dfs = {sheet_name: xl_file.parse(sheet_name) 
      for sheet_name in xl_file.sheet_names}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', encoding='latin1')
```

Comment: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Comment: `encoding` attribute is not supported in new versions of pandas.

Answer (score 1):

if a column of float is writted as a="3.300,144" you should do the following:

```
a = a.replace(".", "")

a = a.replace(",", ".")

float(a)
```

Output **a**

```
33300.144
```